# Azure VM replacement: transfer IP address and FQDN

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I'm helping with an on-going Azure project. An Azure VM is running an antiquated OS (Ubuntu 14.04). That's so old it is entirely outside the support window.

I'd like to create a new VM, transfer content from old to new, and then assign the IP and FQDN to the new system. In a perfect world, clients would never know the old system has been replaced.

I cannot find any documents in Azure about how to claim an IP or DNS name from another VM. I only find docs on creating new VMs.

Worries:

On the old system, when I release the IP and DNS names, I might lose control of the IP number if some new machine grabs it before I find a way to claim it in the new system.

Here is another aspect of the problem.  The previous technician created the old server in EastUS region.  However, we are in the CentralUS region.  Appears to me Azure IPs are contained in regional zones. It is not possible to claim the same EastUS IP number within a new machine in CentralUS. If I'm stuck creating the new VM in EastUS, I can live with that, but it is not optimal because I cannot put it in the same network security group.

Since it costs money to set up systems and try to do these chores, I hope to find somebody who has done this that can help.

The other idea, which did not occur to me till this moment, would be to try to update the Ubuntu OS on the old running VM. I have LOTS of experience doing that kind of thing in workstations, but have never done it in a VM and if the attempt to update the VM makes it quit working, then I'll be in trouble.

I'm open for suggestions. Let me hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Public IP address is not part of the Virtual Machine.  It's a separate ARM resource that's currently associated with the VM's Network Interface.

You can "Disassociate" the IP Address from one VM's Network Interface and "Associate" it with a different VM.

See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-addresses

Comment: Safe to transfer IP across regions?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/move-across-regions-publicip-powershell

Comment: I think it would have been easier for you to just say NO than to paste in a link. "Azure Public IPs cannot be moved between regions. "

Comment: It's more complicated that.  You can create a new "Public IP" resource in the target region reusing the IPv4 address.

Answer (score 2):

so the workflow should be like this: convert public IP to static (will most likely cause VM reboot), dissociate it from the VM and attach to a new one. If you just do the dissociate bit and associate to another VM the IP will change